# DataTemplate for TextBlock and ComboBox in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate

I've got this XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="New_app_2.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I bound TextBlock to a property TestList:

```
private List<string> _testList;

public List<string> TestList
{
    get
    {
        return new List<string>() { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5" };
    }
    set
    {
        _testList = value;
    }
}
```

and a ComboBox to a property Tags (which looks pretty much the same as TestList property, but have different strings).

My goal is to display that in a form like this:

Test1 [Combobox of tags]

Test2 [Combobox of tags]

Test3 [Combobox of tags]

Test4 [Combobox of tags]

Test5 [Combobox of tags]

Instead, I'm getting:

Test1 [Combobox of tags]

Test2

Test3

Test4

Test5

Later, I'd also like to be able to get information which options were chosen for each of TestList elements.

Probably it's very easy, but I've just started learning WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you just move the `ComboBox` *into* the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` then? (You will then need to wrap both `TextBlock` and the `ComboBox` in another panel (e.g. a `StackPanel`).)

If all `ComboBoxes` should contain the same items you will need to change the binding to access the outside `DataContext`.

i.e.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tags,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
```

Comment: It works! But I don't really understand <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tags,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">.

Comment: Another thing: What will I need to do in order to read what the user has chosen in each of ComboBoxes?

Comment: Read the documentation of the [`Binding` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) and its properties/related classes, it's very important. Also there is [this overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx). Here you change the binding source to a document element, because the current `DataContext` (which is the implicit source) was changed to the current templated item. Because the source is now an element you need to specifically get the `DataContext` in the binding path.

Comment: Just bind the `SelectedItem` to a property on your data object. (Change it from a string list to an object list, that contains a `Label` property and a `Value` property, bind the label to the text block, bind the value to the combo box selected item)